# Power BI - How do I get a COUNT of how many Customers have selected "Dairy Milk"?

Tags: database, powerbi

My data looks like :-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IchAZ.png)

---

I want to understand how many Customers have selected "Kit Kat", How many have selected "Munch" and so on like :-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4k0gI.png)

---

How could I achieve something like this in Power BI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first make some conversion using unpivot other columns on the power query editor.

With [customer] column selected, Select the unpivot other columns.(See the below picture)

[image: İmage_1]

After changes, Your table will look like this:

[image: FER]

Then Write this simple DAX Code:

```
CountOfSelection = 
COUNT(Preference[customer])
```

If you test it:

[image: FGD]

You need to filter the blank row not to show its values if you prefer using filters pane, see below picture:

[image: DFG]